# Accidentally gzipped every file in a folder containing website - now ungzipped but site has error 500

Tags: php, web-server, http, website

I accidentally gzipped every file in a folder that contains a website. The webpage are all .php files and the php pages get some information from a mysql database. I then ungzipped everything. If I go on the website (live on the internet), I get a HTTP Error 500. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thank you.. Is there some standard folder I can find the server log?

Comment: this depends on your installation, but you may find some informations in /var/log

Answer (score 2):

The permissions and ownership of the files may have changed during the zip-unzip process. If you're using Apache HTTPD, you may have to change ownership to www-data (either the user or group) to get Apache to use the files.